# React router & Switch - page is not loading after refreshing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

I have problem with proper rendering components in  - right now I have this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={LayoutPage} />
          <Route exact path="/admin-panel" component={AdminPanel} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and

```
function LayoutPage() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/nieruchomosc/:name/:id"
            component={SinglePropertyCard}
          />
          <Route exact path="/nieruchomosci" component={PropertiesPage} />
          <Route exact path="/archiwum" component={HistoryPage} />
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={Conatct} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

Basically I want to render LayoutPage or AdminPanel depending on needs. This work fine but when I am on one of 'child' page (SinglePropertyCard, PropertiesPage, HistoryPage, Conatct) and I refresh the page, everything disapears. Refreshing works fine when I am on main page ('/') or admin page ('admin-panel'). I know that's beacause those two pages are on App component Route. The solution is to put every component from LayoutPage to App component:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={LayoutPage} />

          <Route path="/nieruchomosci" component={PropertiesPage} />
          <Route path="/archiwum" component={HistoryPage} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/nieruchomosc/:name/:id"
            component={SinglePropertyCard}
          />
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={Conatct} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
        <Route path="/admin-panel" component={AdminPanel} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but after that, when I go to AdminPanel page ('/admin-panel), I can see Navbar and Footer, and that's something I do not want to.

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: SOLUTION

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route
          path="/"
          render={
            props =>
              props.location.pathname !== '/admin-panel' ? <Navbar /> : null
          }
        />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={LayoutPage} />

          <Route path="/nieruchomosci" exact component={PropertiesPage} />
          <Route path="/archiwum" component={HistoryPage} />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/nieruchomosc/:name/:id"
            component={SinglePropertyCard}
          />
          <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
        <Route
          path="/"
          render={
            props =>
              props.location.pathname !== '/admin-panel' ? <Footer /> : null
          }
        />

        <Route path="/admin-panel" component={AdminPanel} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to conditionally render `<Navbar />` and `<Footer />` component.
Basically you don't want to render Navbar and Footer on AdminPanel page.You can find current path of the page and render Navbar and Footer when its not your admin-panel path.

```
{this.props.history.location !== 'localhost:3000/admin-panel' && <Navbar />}

{this.props.history.location !== 'localhost:3000/admin-panel' && <Footer />}
```

`this.props.history.location` is used to fint current url of page.

Comment: It took me almost an hour, but I figured it out. I put it above. Thanks! :)